# React Native localhost Another debugger is already connected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, metro-bundler

Not sure if anyone had this problem, since I could not look it up anywhere but I cannot see any logs for react native app because the browser console tells me that "Another debugger is already connected" its a warning that keeps looping.

Metro bundler is telling me that I have to see the javascript logs in the browser. I cannot work on my app without debugging it, can anyone help ?

[image: Metro Terminal]
[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: you must have another tab opened at `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` where a debugger is already running.

Comment: Yes that just solved my problem! @KevinAmiranoff - if you post your answer here I will accept it if you'd like :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This happens if you have another tab opened at `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui` as you can only have one instance of the debugger running.

You could either go back to the already running tab and see the logs there or close the other tab and refresh this one.

Comment: I was having another tab opened in a different web browser, when I left it open in only 1 browser, the issue got fixed. Thanks

Comment: in my case a chrome window had been opened automatically from the day before and I didn't even know about it! It might have been minimized the moment it was launched or something like that.  so look for any open browser windows too.